# Are those Tableau dashboards possible to scrape?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api

I'm trying to scrape data from some Tableau dashboards that I use in a daily basis in order to get a up to date data frame. However, some dashboards  don't seem to appear as  public Tableau ones.
I've used the code below extract data from the public ones, such as "Consumo", based on the TableauScraper package (https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping), but would help me a lot if a could extract data form dashboards like "Geração".

```
    from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://public.tableau.com/shared/CW8T7MTMX?:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
workbook = ts.getWorkbook()

for t in workbook.worksheets:
    print(f"worksheet name : {t.name}") #show worksheet name
    print(t.data) #show dataframe for this worksheet
```

Is there any adaptation which can make it possible?

The dashboards: https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/infomercado?_afrLoop=393990020070066&_adf.ctrl-state=61nwief61_1#!%40%40%3F_afrLoop%3D393990020070066%26_adf.ctrl-state%3D61nwief61_5

Answer (score 0):

The main tableau URL is https://public.tableau.com/views/ConsumodeenergianoSIN/AnlisedeconsumonoSIN

When you click on "Geraçao", it returns https://tableaupub.ccee.org.br/t/CCEE/views/PainelGerao/GeraonoSIN :

```py
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://tableaupub.ccee.org.br/t/CCEE/views/PainelGerao/GeraonoSIN"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
workbook = ts.getWorkbook()

for t in workbook.worksheets:
    print(f"worksheet name : {t.name}") #show worksheet name
    print(t.data) #show dataframe for this worksheet
```

[repl.it link](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/TableauCcee)

Comment: When I click on "Geraçao" there are another five screens with information. Using the URL (https://tableaupub.ccee.org.br/t/CCEE/views/PainelGerao/GeraonoSIN) in the scraping code returns me some useful data, but the one I'm most interested in, the table inside the "Download de Dados" (https://tableaupub.ccee.org.br/t/CCEE/views/PainelGerao/DownloaddeDados?:embed=y&:isGuestRedirectFromVizportal=y&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no&:origin=viz_share_link) screen doesn't result in a data frame. Is there an approach I could take to get the data from this table to a data frame in Python?